# Releasing an image file after display

Tags: vb.net, image, file, autorelease

My app repeatedly displays a TIF file from a directory and closes them.
But when I try to rename the file later, VB says that it is in use by another process.
Here is the code:

```
Imports System.IO

Dim imgRight As Image
Dim fileRight as String 

fileRight = "C:\1_Audit\PD_SE-4423344\PD_SE-4423344_0008.tif"
imgRight = Image.FromFile(fileRight) 
Me.PicBoxRight.Image = imgRight
.
.
.
Me.PicBoxRight.Image.Dispose()
Me.PicBoxRight.Image = Nothing
imgRight.Dispose()
.
.
.
oldFileName = fileRight
newFileName = "PD_SE-4423344_0006.tif"
My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(oldFileName, newFileName)
```

What do I have to do to release fileRight???

Comment: The `using` statement!

Comment: `dim imgRight = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(fileRight)), true, false) [...] PicBoxRight.Image.Dispose()`. Set to `Nothing` to remove it from the view. -- If you don't need `imgRight` for anything else, assign the image directly to the PictureBox.

Comment: @JeremyThompson It's already `Dispose()`ed, so `Using` wouldn't gain anything.

Comment: So if I load the image from a Stream instead of a file, then the file is released as soon as it is read?

Comment: @Jerermy Thompson - I am displaying two pages of a book at a time and going through the whole book. And there can be from 100 to 750 pages per book.

Comment: I implemented using a Stream and it works on my test book of 12 pages. THANK YOU! We'll see if it has any problems with full size books.

Comment: I think if you use a Stream then the file would be released as soon as the Stream is closed and/or disposed.

Comment: @Craig, clearly `Dispose` is not working as it should and is leading to a heap exhaustion situation, but since you're the expert I'll let you solve this one!

Comment: @JeremyThompson I'm certainly no expert (or at least, not an expert in everything).  I would generally recommend to use `Using`, I just don't think it would address the issue in this case since there is already an explicit call to `Dispose`.  I might be wrong, though... maybe there's an exception happening somewhere so that the implicit `Finally` from a `Using` block would release the resource whereas the explicit `Dispose` call gets skipped over.

Comment: We implemented the code using FileStream at our downtown site and it has been very successful. First on releasing files, but it has also drastically increased performance. So we can consider this case closed.